# Symfony, creating new object slow

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to write a foreach loop where users get subscribed and inserted into the database using doctrine. My code:

```
$i=0;
$batchSize=20;

foreach ($members as $member) {
    $subscription = new Subscription($company, $user);
    $entityManager->persist($subscription);
    // debug
    $i++;
    error_log($i);

    if ($i % $batchSize === 0) {
        $entityManager->flush();
        $entityManager->clear();
    }
}
```

this code is really slow. For about 100 users, this code needs a couple minutes to execute. This should be a lot faster right?

When I delete the object creation (and the setMember, and entityManager lines) this code is executed is less than a second.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE: Entity code**
*I changed some variables because of code secrets. If any code is wrong, it's because of the fast changes I made so I could post my issue here.*

```
class Subscription implements \JsonSerializable
{

    protected $id;
    protected $company;
    protected $user;
    private $created_on;
    private $blocked;
    private $attributes;

    public function __construct(Company $company, User $user)
    {
        $this->company = $company;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->created_on = new \DateTime();
        $this->blocked = false;

        $this->attributes = new AttributeCollection();

        $this->setDefaultAttributes();
    }

    public function jsonSerialize() {
        return array(
            'id' => $this->id,
            'user' => $this->user,
            'blocked' => $this->blocked,
            'created_on' => $this->created_on->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        );
    }
    // due to company secrets variables have been changed to a,b,c,d,e,f
    public function setDefaultAttributes()
    {
        if (null == $this->attributes)
            $this->attributes = new AttributeCollection();
        $this->attributes->addAttribute(new Attribute('a'));
        $this->attributes->addAttribute(new Attribute('b'));
        $this->attributes->addAttribute(new Attribute('c'));
        $this->attributes->addAttribute(new Attribute('d'));
        $this->attributes->addAttribute(new Attribute('e'));
        $this->attributes->addAttribute(new Attribute('f'));
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setUser(User $user = null)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function setCompany(Company $company = null)
    {
        $this->company = $company;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getCompany()
    {
        return $this->company;
    }

    public function getCreatedOn()
    {
        return $this->created_on;
    }

    public function setBlocked($blocked)
    {
        $this->blocked = $blocked;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getBlocked()
    {
        return $this->blocked;
    }

    public function setAttributes(AttributeCollection $attributes = null)
    {
        $this->attributes = $attributes;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getAttributes()
    {
        return $this->attributes;
    }

}
```

AttributeCollection class used in the Subscription class above:

```
class AttributeCollection
{

    protected $id;
    protected $attributes;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->attributes = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function removeDefaults()
    {
        foreach ($this->attributes as $attribute)
            if ($attribute->isSystemDefault())
                $this->removeAttribute($attribute);
    }

    public function clearDefaults()
    {
        foreach ($this->attributes as $attribute)
            $attribute->setSystemDefault(false);
    }

    public function getAttributes()
    {
        return $this->attributes;
    }

    public function addAttribute(Attribute $attribute)
    {
        if (!$this->findAttributeByName($attribute->getName()))
            $this->attributes[] = $attribute;
    }

    public function removeAttribute(Attribute $attribute)
    {
        $this->attributes->removeElement($attribute);
    }

    public function findAttributeByName($name)
    {
        foreach ($this->attributes as $attribute)
            if ($attribute->getName() == $name)
                return $attribute;
        return;
    }

    public function get($name)
    {
        $attribute = $this->findAttributeByName($name);
        if ($attribute)
            return $attribute->getValue();
        return;
    }

    public function getAll()
    {
        return $this->attributes->toArray();
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe flushing `20` entities is a time-consuming task. Have you tried lowering `$batchSize`?

Comment: @D4V1D well I now know that it's the model creation which is time-consuming. If I delete the doctrine related lines, and leave the model creation. It takes equally as long.

Comment: What does the line `error_log($i);` do? I mean which handler does it use? Does it open/close log file each time?

Comment: @JovanPerovic It just writes $i to a log file. I know that's not the problem, because I `tail -f` the file. And without the model creation, the $i's get instantly printed.

Comment: I see. Did you try running this in `prod`? If so, what were the results there?

Comment: Also, `couple minutes to execute`? That much huh?

Comment: @JovanPerovic i cant run in prod due to AppleDouble issues which I can't resolve. And yes, really a couple of minutes :(

Comment: post code of all your entities that are persisted in this loop.

Comment: Your code seems incorrect. Why do you use `$subscription = new Subscription();` instead of  `$subscription = new Subscription($company, $member);` ?

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov edited, that didn't caused the problem. It's still slow

Comment: Also post your `Member` and `Attribute` entities and all listeners that related to persisting/flushing.

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov I fixed it. It had nothing to do with the original models. It probably isn't such a good idea to pass those models through a constructor. I'll post the solution as an answer.

Comment: We try to discourage commentary about voting in posts (either asking people to upvote, or not to downvote, or to explain their downvotes) since this isn't of interest to most people who just want to read questions and answers (especially at the start of a question). You can put these points in comments if you wish, though I personally wouldn't bother - 500+ rep should insulate you nicely from any posting problems associated with downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that passing those models through the constructor caused the problem.

I changed my code:

```
class Subscription {
    ...
    public function __construct($Company == null, $member == null) {
        ...
    }
}
```

and in my foreach loop:

```
$subscription = new Subscription();
$subscription->setCompany($company);
$subscription->setMember($member);
```

this way everything runs smooth and as expected. I have no idea why the constructor is slowing everything down. But apparently it did.

Answer (score 0):

It is not optimal to use such small `$batchSize` for such small entities.

This way of persisting is presented in documentation as an example of how you can optimize your memory and connection loading, not the speed of whole script.

If you remove these checks on `$i` and `$batchSize` it will be faster.

```
foreach ($members as $member) {
    $subscription = new Subscription();
    $subscription->setMember($member);
    $entityManager->persist($subscription);
}
$entityManager->flush();
```

Also keep in mind that in dev-env you have `debug` option is set as `enabled` and all queries to the DB are logged in files. It also waste a time.

Comment: as stated above "When I delete the object creation (and the setMember, and entityManager lines) this code is executed is less than a second." The $i + $batchSize checks are not my problem

Comment: not the check. I mean `$entityManager->flush();` and `$entityManager->clear();` if you will have only one flush after all manipulations it will be faster.

Comment: also those flushes and clears aren't the problem. I deleted those and only left the model creation. It seems that the creation of the model takes a very long time.

Comment: What is he has, say, 500+ members? He is bound to exhaust RAM in no time. I think his approach is correct. @AngeloA: What does the `new Subscription();` do? Does it create some internal objects within entity?

Comment: @JovanPerovic I mean that if he will have about 100 members and have not heavy entities then he doesn't need to use this "optimization".

Comment: @JovanPerovic yes, it does create one internal class, which is an ArrayCollection and contains simple key value objects. Nothing big.

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov: True. Wonder if that `ArrayCollection` could introduces slowness...